# Phantom Multimedia Message

Tags: contacts, sms, mms

At regular, though infrequent, intervals I receive a multi media message in my inbox from 'δ@' which has no content. The message is completely blank. I do not have such a contact and I receive mmms so little that I'm sure it cannot actually be a real message from someone I know.

I have a HTC Desire with Android 2.2 on Orange (UK).

What is this and what can I do about it?

Comment: I have the same problem. HTC Desire 2.2 on Orange, and I get them all the time. The message details say
Type: SMS message
From: Δ@ [although in the message it actually says δ@]
Recieved: 28/12/10

Maybe an Orange problem?

Comment: Rather late in the day, but here's a thread about the same issue - it does sound like it's related to Orange UK's voicemail, and possibly was specific to HTC phones running Android 2.2? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=609019

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to long-press on the text, and select View Message Details, this should give you the actual phone number it was sent from.

With this in hand you can go through your phone book and double-check that it's not anyone you know.

If it's not then you should be able to contact your service provider and ask them to block messages from that number. Also, many automated text services that use short message codes to send are set to remove you from their list if you reply with just the word `STOP` in a text message.

Comment: There is no text in the message - it's completely blank.